# Basic traffic volume map

Tags: symbology, network, analysis

I'm trying to map the volume of people travelling from various cities to popular mountain towns in British Columbia. I have a CSV containing the starting point, ending point and number of travellers. There must be a way to show the volume of travel (thickness of line, or colour coded) from place to place using city layer polygons and a road network layer.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Which software you are using to show the map? for ex. QGIS or ArcGIS thanks..

Comment: To add to what @Sunil is saying, you can also do it with Google Earth or a web interface. But we need to know your platform. If you don't have one, then please indicate that as well

Comment: i am using qgis

Answer (score 0):

We have done so using our RW Net 4 package for calculating flow from your CSV-data and then used line thickness for illustration of volume. In this example all flows are from a single location:
http://www.routeware.dk/wordpress/?p=61

Comment: Which algorithms are you guys using for Route assignment?

Comment: We are using A*.

Comment: I dont really care about the route, as travel is over a considerable about of distance with limited route options. I am using QGIS, is there a to do that in this?